# How can I achieve a Website, Android app, and Iphone App with one development?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

I want to develop a website, along with an android app and an iphone app.

The basic features/needs of the program are:

- Use of geolocation to discover where the user is located
- A payment system for users to send payments.

My question is what development route can I take to accomplish all 3 at once - or with very little needed to go between the 3. The website might be php + javascript, Android is java, and Iphone is objective-c. I dont want to do 3 seperate developments, just 1 and it must have all my needed functionality.

As an example, think of groupon.com (although this program is not anything related). They have a site, iphone app, and android app.

If you suggest something like Phonegap, why do you suggest that, and what are the downfalls of it?

Comment: He should do more than that. This is not a specific question whatsoever.

Answer (score 2):

You have many options, better use mobile jquery or sencha framework and deploy it as website+apps.

Phonegap can access your default apis.
So if you want pin-point location, go with Phonegap, but you cannot use it in mobile site.
In mobile site you can use Google Apis.

Comment: Do note that you can use GPS in a webbrowser. Also, there's always a tradeoff, Phonegap has its downsides too.